# Get the link of an specific xml file from the server (php script) and load it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

In the web site I am creating a user can upload and download files and I create an xml log with operation informations. 
In the website there is a page where a table of the log xml is created reading the xml.

It worked fine when it was all in my hard disk but now that I started hosting it on a server I don't know how to make it work.

In local computer the xml request was

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.xml",false);
```

Now in the real web site I need to make an ajax call to a php script to geth the path of my personal xml file.

First question: what kind of address i need to output from the php script?

```
http://mywebsite/folder1/folder2/log_username.xml
```

Is something like this?

With the ajax call I save the address in a variable and the xml request became:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",xml_address_variable,false);
```

The problem is that  the XML isn't loaded. Where is the problem?

EDITED: now that i wrote in the javascript code the path of a specific user for experiment it worked, but if I put the variable (link_xml) where the AJAX call should save the path it doesn't work so this is the critical part of my code:

```
var link_xml = askXMLaddress();

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",link_xml,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Answer (score 1):

for ajax to load it you'd need a file path from your doc-root. so if you want

```
http://mywebsite/folder1/folder2/log_username.xml
```

all JS needs is

```
../folder1/folder2/log_username.xml
```

then you can use jquery.load() like so

```
 var path = <?php echo "../folder1/folder2/log_username.xml"; ?>;
 $( "#username" ).load(path);
```

now instead of that 'php echo...' stuff you'd probably do better to use another ajax request. BUT that will depend on your use case.

Comment: I need to write ".." at the start?
I tried putting in the javascript the path for one specific user manually in the javascript but the document doesn't load.
I need to use plain javascript no jquery thanks!

Comment: oh, then I would guess your problem could be file permissions. but here's some code using JS without extra libraries.

Comment: where is the extra code? Do i need the ".." at the beginning of the path or I can write /folder1/folder2/log_username.xml ?

Comment: sorry I was writing it, :P check my second answer, and you don't always need the extra '..' its just so that if you're running a script from a sub directory (ie not from your doc-root) that script WILL run from the root, instead of the scripts default running directory. Also i should mention that '..' is a JS thing, PHP won't understand it.

Comment: BIG THANKS TO YOU!!!!!! It worked!!! The problem was in the path. /folder1/folder2/log_username.xml

Comment: Ok, now it work if I specify the path in the javascript file. If I load it with the AJAX call and put it in a variable before loading the xml it doesn't work. The echoed path from php is right. I'm adding my code in the first post if can help. Could the problem be that the server response isn't immediate so the path isn't written in the javascript variable from the ajax request?

Comment: remember PHP happens server-side before things get to the users browser. so php should certainly be putting the string in the right place. in the PHP, try ** echo JSON_encode("path");** and in the js, alert that to the browser to see what it passes. (use alert(?php echo JSON_encode("path");?>); in JS)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44447/discussion-between-newtphp-and-matutter)

Comment: In PHP i have echo $path; in JS I have var link_xml = xmlhttp.responseText; and return link_xml; if in JS after these two lines I alert(link_xml) I read the correct path. I think the return doesn't work becasue in the JS function to load XML this variable var link_xml = askXMLaddress(); if alerted is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadXML(path, selector)
{
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        xml.open("GET", path, false);
        xml.send(null);
    }
    catch (e) {
       //some error stuff
    }
    document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML=xml.responseText;
}
```

I can't guarentee this works I don't have a server parsing xml stuff at the moment.

Comment: so if i have a html element like <xmlgoeshere> </xmlgoeshere> 
then my selector would be "xmlgoeshere" if you want to display the content of that xml page somewhere in the current DOM.

Comment: Ah ok, I already did that (the table i mentioned.) But it's still not working...I will check my code. Thanks.