# Problems understanding/using callback function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909470/get-the-link-of-an-specific-xml-file-from-the-server-php-script-and-load-it-in/20909624#20909624) discussion and in chat I understood that a callback is the only way to go!

"
Get from the server a link with ajax, write the link in a variable, open an xml with this link, doing some stuff with the xml: is callback the only way?
"

I'm trying to understand what a callback is. I read some blog, but I still have problems.

What I have now in JS is

1) a function to open an xml.

2) function to request the link of the xml in first function

Can someone provide an example in PLAIN JAVASCRIPT of how to nest these two functions?

The server generate the link of the xml because I'm making a multi user web site and every user has it's own xml. So I need to ask the server what is the link of the xml and then open it. Is there an easy way to achieve this? I need plain javascript no jquery.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "request the link of the xml in 1"?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: added more informations in the first post

Answer (score 2):

In general, a "callback" is a function which will be executed at a later time when an asynchronous process is completed.

So you might start by defining the function that should happen when the data is retrieved from the server (the "second" function, intuitively, but you should define it first because it's the business functionality you're looking to achieve and not just an implementation concern).  Something as simple as:

```
var doSomethingWithTheData = function () {
    // do, well, something with the data
};
```

This assumes that you have the data, which you don't yet.  But the AJAX call will get that data.  You can now use this function as your callback for the AJAX call.  Taking the [AJAX example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), you might have this:

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = doSomethingWithTheData;
// perform the AJAX request
```

The `httpRequest` object will contain the response from the server after the AJAX call is executed and completed.  (Remember that this happens asynchronously, so it won't contain the response on the immediate next line of code.  It will at some later time which you don't control.  Hence the need for the callback.)

I recommend walking through that full MDN article to get all the details, particularly on handling errors and such.  But the data you're looking for (assuming nothing went wrong) would be in `httpRequest.ResponseText`.  So, also assuming your variables are scoped to allow this (you can modify that as needed):

```
var doSomethingWithTheData = function () {
    var data = httpRequest.ResponseText;
    // do, well, something with the data
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. A user said I don't need callback to get the link of an XML file and then open it. I don't understand If I really need it. I added more information to the first post. Can you tell me if there is a simple way to make what I need? Thanks.

Comment: @newtphp: I think that other answer is using a slightly different definition of "callback" in this case.  That's a special kind of AJAX request (JSONP) which follows a specific standard used for cross-domain requests.  I don't think you need that.  But the JavaScript "callback" function in my answer is just the code which gets executed when the AJAX call completes.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, @David

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, 
   httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
   httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "http://myserver.mydomain/getMyUsersXMLUrl?user=pete";
httpRequest.open("GET", url, true); // next ajax to retrieve XML - File
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) { // response received
      var response = httpRequest.responseText; // this should contain you url

      httpRequest.open("GET", response, true); // next ajax to retrieve XML - File
      // and the same as for the first request
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You just need to download a xml you dont need a callback . Just take a look at jquery and ajax. Retrieving a callback from a server is not  possible . JSONP does deal with callbacks that are called by the server (actually they arent ) Butter you wont need it. I think you are messaging the xhttprequestobject

Comment: The server generate the link of the xml because I'm making a multi user web site and every user has it's own xml. So I need to ask the server what is the link of the xml and then open it. Is there an easy way to achieve this? I need plain javascript no jquery.

Comment: Simple. That are two requests, the First to Retrieve  the right url for the xml File you want the second to download it.

Comment: The problem is that if I make the first request for the url with ajax when I try to open it the variable that should hold the link is undefined.

Comment: That's what is mentioned in the answers above . Ajax is asynchron so your ajax call wont make your code execution stop waiting for the result of the call.instead program execution is continued .simplest form to avoid this is checking the state of your ajax request .when it hast completed you can  retrieve the result and then make the Nextel request .but if you check the state in a loop your application will block and you will get an unresponsive skript message. So you would Use settimeout and check every 1sec Ort something

Comment: Puh waiting with Mythen smartphone gives interesting word completed. :D

Comment: Writing with My smartphone

Comment: Var url = responseText ; next ajax } Gott the ideal?

Comment: Yes I got the message! But I'm missing something. I fixed it in a bad way but at least it works: I created a hidden div and with php i wrote in it the xml url. So when the function openXML() is loaded it just read with document.getElementById(id_name).innetHTML the url and no ajax call is made to get the url.

Answer (score 0):

A [callback function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) is simply a piece of executable code passed as a parameter to another piece of code. For example:

```
function first (arr, predicate) {
    // no predicate supplied, return first element
    if (!predicate) return arr[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // return first element satisfying predicate
        if (predicate(arr[i])) return arr[i];
    }

    // no element satisfying predicate, return null
    return null;
}

// second parameter is an anonymous function
// will alert 4, as it's the first element which will return true
alert(first([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(n) { return n > 3; }));
```

Callbacks are useful for asynchronous tasks, or for library functions which need extra customization at runtime.